# using for loop to replace bad nucleotides from DNA sequence

Tags: python, for-loop, replace, dna-sequence

I have a list of sequences (for simplicity like the following one)

```
seqList=["ACCTGCCSSSTTTCCT","ACCTGCCFFFTTTCCT"]
```

and I want to use for looping to replace every instance of a nucleotide other than ["A","C","G","T"] with "N"

my code so far

```
seqList=["ACCTGCCSSSTTTCCT","ACCTGCCFFFTTTCCT"]
for x in range(len(seqList)):
    for i in range(len(seqList[x])):
        if seqList[x][i] not in ["A","C","G","T"]:
            seqList[x][i].replace(seqList[x][i],"N")
            print(seqList)
```

problem is, the nucleotides are not replaced and nothing changes in the original sequence
and i can't figure out the reason!!!

Comment: `import re` `seqList = [re.sub('[^AGTC]', 'N', item) for item in seqList]`

Comment: works like a charm, thank you @ChrisCharley

Answer (score 1):

Strings in python are immutable.
You can make ot work like this

```
seqList=  ["ACCTGCCSSSTTTCCT","ACCTGCCFFFTTTCCT"]
for x in range(len(seqList)):
    stringl=list(seqList[x])
    for i in range(len(seqList[x])):
        if seqList[x][i] not in ["A","C","G","T"]:
            stringl[i]="N"
    seqList[x]="".join(stringl)
```

Comment: It worked, thanks.                                                                                                                                the .m part is probably a typo though

Comment: Yes, I was using mobile to write this.

Answer (score 0):

An aprouch without looping all letters would be replacing all letters which are not `ACGT`

```
def replace_bad(seq):
    unique = [
        letter
        for letter in set(seq)
        if letter not in "ACGT"
    ]

    for each in unique:
        seq = seq.replace(each, "N")

    return seq


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for seq in seqList:
        print(replace_bad(seq))
```